What is the rails way to update a price field before update in a model object generating a total?
I have an order form with selectors for a product and boolean sliders for add-on options.  I want to calculate the total price before saving to the db.  I am using a before_save :set_total action in the model, but I can't change the value of the price field.  Are model values read only?  If so, where should I put the model object 'set_total' to affect the price value?  I don't think it is wise to use an after-save :set_total with an update olineorders set price = #{tot price};
my model file extract:
class Olineorder < ApplicationRecord

    before_save :set_total
    
    (other stuff in here)
    
private

    def set_total

        puts "\n\ndef set_total"
        puts "\tprice: #{price.inspect}\t#{Olineorder.inspect}\t\n"
        
            @a = Price.find_by_sql("select pr.product_id, pr.price as theprice, p.name from prices as pr, products as p where pr.product_id == p.id;")
            @b = Hash.new
            @a.each do |f|
                @b[f.name] = f.theprice.to_f
#               puts f.name, f.theprice
            end

        totprice = @b["#{selection}"]
        totprice += @b["Certificate"] if cert == true
        totprice += @b["Biographical Skectch"] if bio == true
        totprice += @b["Photograph"] if pic == true
        self.price = printf('$%.2f',totprice)
==>Note:  I al so tried:  price = ....  with same result. <===

        puts "\n\tprice: #{price.inspect}  -- total price -- #{totprice}\t#{Olineorder.inspect}\t\n"
        puts "\ndef_set_toal ---<<< END\n"
        
    end

Below is the logging output in the development.log
------------------ Output in log file ---------------
Started POST "/olineorders" for ::1 at 2024-10-14 18:04:10 -0700
Processing by OlineordersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "olineorder"=>{--REDACTED---, "selection"=>"Worker's Brick", "cert"=>"true", "bio"=>"true", "pic"=>"true", "brick1"=>"", "brick2"=>"", "brick3"=>"", "price"=>"0.00", "comments"=>"", "block"=>"", "log"=>"0", "status"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Olineorder"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["remember_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:14:in `ck_for_accs_level'
  Product Load (0.1ms)  select id, name from products;
  ↳ app/controllers/olineorders_controller.rb:113:in `set_product_list'


def set_total
    price: "0.00"   Olineorder(id: integer, last_name: string, first_name: string, address1: string, address2: string, city: string, state: string, zip: string, phone: string, email: string, selection: string, cert: boolean, bio: boolean, pic: boolean, comments: string, block: string, log: string, brick1: string, brick2: string, brick3: string, status: string, price: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/olineorder.rb:35:in `set_total'
  Price Load (0.4ms)  select pr.product_id, pr.price as theprice, p.name from prices as pr, products as p where pr.product_id == p.id;
  ↳ app/models/olineorder.rb:35:in `set_total'
$135.00
    price: nil  -- total price -- 135.0 Olineorder(id: integer--redacted---, price: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

def_set_toal ---<<< END
  Olineorder Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "olineorders" (---redacted---- "price", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [---REDACTED---, ["price", "0.00"], ["created_at", "2024-10-15 01:04:11.142454"], ["updated_at", "2024-10-15 01:04:11.142454"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/olineorders_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/olineorders_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/olineorders/17
Completed 302 Found in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms (4 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/olineorders/17" for ::1 at 2024-10-14 18:04:11 -0700
Processing by OlineordersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
  Olineorder Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "olineorders".* FROM "olineorders" WHERE "olineorders"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/olineorders_controller.rb:109:in `set_olineorder'
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["remember_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:14:in `ck_for_accs_level'
  Product Load (0.0ms)  select id, name from products;
  ↳ app/controllers/olineorders_controller.rb:113:in `set_product_list'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering olineorders/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered olineorders/_olineorder.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | GC: 0.0ms)
  Rendered olineorders/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.7ms | GC: 0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_pg_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | GC: 0.0ms)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.3ms | GC: 0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms (3 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.2ms)


self.price = printf('$%.2f',totprice)

This does not set the price, it prints it. printf is for printing and returns nil so that does self.price = nil. You want sprintf.
If price is a number you probably don't want to add a $ to it. Generally avoid adding formatting to numbers in your database, it makes them harder to work with. In that case, use Numeric#round.
self.price = totprice.round(2)


Notes

@a and @b are instance variables on the object which will persist. You probably don't want that, and you risk accidentally overwriting other instance variables such as @price. If you just need a local variable in a method use a and b... tho don't use a and b, use descriptive names. See Read This If You Want to Understand Instance Variables in Ruby.
It's generally not necessary to check if cert == true. if cert is sufficient.

Consider using rubocop and rubocop-rails to guide you.

Thank you Schwern, for answering the actual question and providing the solution that worked.  I pulled printf from some sqlite3 code that formatted a number to price...did not understand that printf acted differently.  Thank you also for your comments about '@'a vs 'a'.  That was poor coding on my part.  I learned to code back when memory space was a critical limit.  I am trying to break that habit but was forced to come back after 10 years when the vendor site running our small not for profit sold out to a larger corporation that would not honor current app/enviornments.

I'm sorry but you completely missed the mark completely here, and there really isn't much code thats worthwile to salvage.
I'll instead show a basic sketch of how you want to approach the problem:
# rails g model order total:decimal status:integer
# This model should be created as soon as the user adds the first item to the order
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items

  # You'll want to add these later
  # belongs_to :customer
  # has_many :payments
end

# rails g model product name price:decimal
# What you call Certificate, Biographical Sketch etc really just 
# seem like products and can most likely be modeled in a more generic way
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
end

# rails g model line_item order:references product:references price:references
# This model represents a single line on a order form and joins 
# orders to products. 
# Every time an item is added to the order a line items should be created.
# The line item also records the price of the product at the time it's added to the order. 
# This avoids chaos if an order is updated after prices have changed. 
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end 

To tally up the total of an order you just sum all the line items*:
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items

  def gross_total
    line_items.sum(:price)
  end

  def finalize!
    update!(total: gross_total, status: :awaiting_confirmation)
  end
end

I would not use a callback to record the total as it's difficult to control when callbacks are fired. Instead do it as an explicit step when the user actually checks out the order.
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def finalize!
    update(total: gross_total, status: :awaiting_confirmation)
  end
end

class CheckoutService
  def initialize(order)
    @order = order
  end 

  def call
    @order.finalize!
    # ... @todo send order confirmation
  end

  # ...
end

This is greatly simplefied - in reality you're going to have to add more complexity in the form of quantities, rebates, taxes etc.
Money should either be recorded as an integer in the smallest denomination (cents) or as decimal. Using formatted strings is going to be a nightmare to work with.
Suggested reading:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms


Thank you Max for your thoughtful response.  You are correct in your assessment of the model we have inherited.  I will study your suggestions to lean how to implement them.  Thanks again.
